# org.eclipse.tm4e.core.TMException: No grammar provided for <text.html.basic>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, textmate

I created a spring boot project and added starter dependencies Thymeleaf and spring mvc and i wanted to create a html ffile in Templates folder but encountered error org.eclipse.tm4e.core.TMException: No grammar provided for <text.html.basic>
at org.eclipse.tm4e.core.internal.grammar.dependencies.ScopeDependencyProcessor.collectReferencesOfReference(ScopeDependencyProcessor.java:117)
at org.eclipse.tm4e.core.internal.grammar.dependencies.ScopeDependencyProcessor.processQueue(ScopeDependencyProcessor.java:82)
at org.eclipse.tm4e.core.registry.Registry._loadGrammar(Registry.java:138)
at org.eclipse.tm4e.core.registry.Registry.loadGrammar(Registry.java:125)
at org.eclipse.tm4e.registry.internal.AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.getGrammar(AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.java:177)
at org.eclipse.tm4e.registry.internal.AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.getGrammarForScope(AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.java:127)
at org.eclipse.tm4e.registry.internal.AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.getGrammarFor(AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.java:115)
at org.eclipse.tm4e.ui.text.TMPresentationReconciler.findGrammar(TMPresentationReconciler.java:347)
at org.eclipse.tm4e.ui.text.TMPresentationReconciler$TextViewerListener.inputDocumentChanged(TMPresentationReconciler.java:216)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.fireInputDocumentChanged(TextViewer.java:2849)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.setDocument(TextViewer.java:2890)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.setDocument(SourceViewer.java:682)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.setDocument(ProjectionViewer.java:368)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.setDocument(SourceViewer.java:632)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.initializeSourceViewer(AbstractTextEditor.java:3980)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3472)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:64)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:445)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.genericeditor.ExtensionBasedTextEditor.createPartControl(ExtensionBasedTextEditor.java:175)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:158)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:365)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:971)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:936)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:142)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:313)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:995)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.lambda$0(PartServiceImpl.java:105)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:183)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4803)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.DisplayUISynchronize.syncExec(DisplayUISynchronize.java:34)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:133)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:661)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:625)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:796)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3233)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$11(WorkbenchPage.java:3123)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:67)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3121)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3091)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3082)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:548)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:508)
at org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.internal.wizard.NewHTMLWizard$1.run(NewHTMLWizard.java:81)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:132)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4047)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3663)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:342)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:645)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:342)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:552)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1432)

I checked in plugin section i found the plugins related to TM4E installed in my Eclipse IDE still i tried to install it from https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest/ from install softaware section but got an error again Could not find https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest/